# One app servers many domains

Tags: meteor

While reading [Example Directory Layout](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#example-app-structure), line 23 in the grey says

> can be split by domain if there are many

Does that mean that www.abc.com and www.xyz.com can be served different `ui` from the same Meteor app? and if so, how does the nodeJS server allow requests from different domains to login? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "Example Directory Layout" section of the [Meteor Guide](https://guide.meteor.com), "domain" isn't being used to represent an Internet based domain. The guide is referring to a [domain model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model).

It is possible to have multiple different domains point to the same Meteor app, and leverage routing to control the UI shown, but Meteor doesn't currently support sharing login state across different domains/sub-domains. One way to work around this for sub-domains is by leveraging browser cookies. See the [kadira:login-state](https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-login-state) package for more info.